# Creating mysql stored proc with one in and int parameter

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE SelectPetDetails
(
IN PetId int
) 
BEGIN
SELECT *  FROM pet p JOIN animal a on p.int_AnimalId=a.int_AnimalId JOIN breed b on a.int_BreedId=b.int_BreedId JOIN colorpattern c ON a.int_ColorPatternId=c.int_ColorPatternId WHERE int_PetOwnerId= PetId
END
```

What's wrong with my creation of stored proc?

Comment: statement not terminated, delimiters not set https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create stored procedures you must change the default delimiter `;` to another character like '$$' or '//' or any that you want.

```
-- must change ; to $$ because stored procedure can have ; multiple times
DELIMITER $$  
drop procedure if exists SelectPetDetails$$  -- if you plan execute this many times
CREATE PROCEDURE SelectPetDetails (IN PetId int) 
BEGIN
    SELECT *  FROM pet p 
        JOIN animal a on p.int_AnimalId=a.int_AnimalId 
        JOIN breed b on a.int_BreedId=b.int_BreedId 
        JOIN colorpattern c ON a.int_ColorPatternId=c.int_ColorPatternId 
    WHERE int_PetOwnerId = PetId;
-- mark as end of stored procedure body 
END $$ 

DELIMITER ; 
-- return to regular delimiter
```